# Cannot copy .bak file to docker container

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, docker

I have SQL Server installed on my mac and need to restore backup file.

I tried this command

```
docker cp ~/Documents/VchasnoCRM.bak container-name:/tmp/vchasno.bak
```

But I got this error.

> No such container:path: container-name:/tmp

But it was working some times ago. Information is from this link: https://medium.com/@reverentgeek/sql-server-running-on-a-mac-3efafda48861

Maybe someone faced this problem? How I can solve this?

Comment: I'm having that exact same problem. It was working for over a year and now it's not after a recent reboot. EDIT: Got it to work. Docker wanted a full path from server root on the container side. Relative path from working directory is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do `docker ps -a` to get a list of containers and make sure a container with that name exists. If it does then `docker exec` into the container to make sure the path exists.

Answer (score 0):

Run "docker ps" command in terminal to get your container name and replace your container name with container-name in the command.

Let me know if that help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for me works only ID container.
*Try restore .bak from windows to mac-docker.*

`myxx-MacBook:/ myxx$ docker ps -a`

`CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS       PORTS                    NAMES abcIDdocker1234   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CU5-ubuntu-18.04   "/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   18 hours ago   Up 3 hours   0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp   sql_container`

`myxx-MacBook:/ myxx$ docker cp 'Users/myxx/Projects/Db/APP_20220619.bak' abcIDdocker1234:'var/opt/mssql/backup/APP_20220619.bak`